# Tagging questions related to Python-based packages

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

When tagging questions related to Python-based packages — such as [cplex-python-api](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cplex-python-api), [cvxpy](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cvxpy), [pulp](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pulp), [pyomo](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyomo) — tag [python](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) is sometimes included and sometimes not. It would be nice to have a policy on this.

In my humble opinion, if there is room for an extra tag, then the "mother tag" [python](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) should always be included, though [not everyone agrees](https://or.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2993). Imagine that someone who is fond of Python visits Operations Research SE for the first time.  That someone can click on tag [python](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), take a look at the related tags and find about, say, CVXPY and PuLP.  If there is room for tag [python](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), why would one want to deprive neophytes and outsiders of the opportunity to quickly learn about the tools of the trade? If the cost is zero and the payoff is nonnegative, why object to it?

Comment: Although I get your argument about those who are fond of the language and can learn new things by looking at a tag like `python`, I found using `python` with `cvxpy` (in your example) redundant. `cvxpy` or `pulp` are python packages. With that argument, we can keep generalizing tags. e.g. maybe we should then start tagging all `cplex`, `gurobi` and such with a `solver` tag as well, in hope someone can learn what are the solvers. That's my opinion but I'm curious to see what others think and hopefully, we can have some standards around it. And thanks for the question.

Comment: @EhsanK And why is redundancy bad? By embracing redundancy when tagging a question related to, say, CVXPY, perhaps other Python-related questions will show up in the `Related` column. Also, perhaps search engines will direct more people to OR SE, which should produce more good than harm. Ideally, SE would have tag hierarchies with "mother tags" and "children tags" — like Quora — and one would be able to search not only within a tag, but also within its children, but we have no such luck.

Comment: @EhsanK, in your example, `python` *isn't* redundant.  I might search for `python` because it's the language I'm comfortable using, but if I've never heard of `cvxpy` I'd never think of searching for it and I'd never find that perfect answer to my problem.

Comment: I'm with Rodrigo on this. Using the python tag, whether redundant or not, costs nothing and might assist some users.

Comment: I agree that redundancy is not a problem. To take an example from another site, on tex.SE, I frequently tag questions with `tikz-pgf` (a LaTeX graphics package) _plus_ `edge` or some other object within the `tikz-pgf` package.

Comment: Fair enough @RayButterworth and everyone else. I actually looked at SO and saw questions with `numpy` are also tagged with `python`. I am a convert.

Answer (score 2):

I generally agree with this proposal, and it goes to show that tag curation is often somewhat inconsistent.

In particular to your question, retagging questions related to Python-based modelling packages is a very doable case. A quick [advanced search](https://or.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcplex-python-api%5D+or+%5Bcvxpy%5D+or+%5Bpulp%5D+or+%5Bpyomo%5D+and+-%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aquestion) brings up 51 potential questions to be retagged with the addition of [python](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python). These are *potential* questions because

- there may already be five relevant tags on a question;
- a question asking about such packages may not be intrinsically related to Python; for instance [What is the purpose of libraries like Pyomo and Google OR tools?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/what-is-the-purpose-of-libraries-like-pyomo-and-google-or-tools) is a "meta-library" question, so take care not to robo-tag.

It is important to avoid mass retagging as it would flood the main page with questions pertaining to one topic only and would deprive new questions of attention. Advice from related sites suggests no more than five instances per day, but due to our site being smaller I would go for a maximum of three of these retagging edits per day.

On a wider note, it may be helpful to form guidelines on the limits of these encompassing tags, or whether there should be limits at all. For example, how far do we want to go with [solver](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solver) (as raised in the comments), [constraint](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constraint) or [optimization](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization)?